# Dynamic routing list items

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have the following code

(tags component ts)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tags',
  templateUrl: './tags.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tags.component.css']
})
export class TagsComponent implements OnInit{

Tags= [
'red',
'blue',
'purple'
];
  red : boolean
  blue : boolean
  purple : boolean

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute ) {}
   ngOnInit(){
  this.Tags= this.route.snapshot.params['name']


    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.red = this.Tags.includes ('red');
        this.purple = this.Tags.includes ('purple');
        this.blue = this.Tags.includes ('blue');
    }
  );
   }
  }
```

(tag component html)

```
 <ul>
  <a><li *ngIf="red">red</li></a>
  <a><li *ngIf="blue">blue</li></a>
  <a><li *ngIf="purple">purple</li></a>
</ul>
```

(app module)

```
const appRoutes: Routes= [
  {path:'', component: AppComponent},
  {path:'tags/:name', component: TagsComponent}
];
```

Right now when I write the URL with the colour name in it only the colour mentioned would appear in the list item which is exactly what I want to do.

example 
[image]

Now everything is hardcoded I want to be able to write any other colour that is not in my array like green and get the array to update and my list items to show accordingly.

I am quite new to this so I know my question might be a bit basic but any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your example you want to format the url like that with a `,` separating the tag params then `split` on the `,` and use a `ngFor` loop in the html to render each tag.

Try this

```
export class TagsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  public tags: string[];

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setTags(this.route.snapshot.params);
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => this.setTags(params));
  }

  private setTags(params): void {
    if (!params || !params['name']) { return; }
    this.tags = params['name'].split(',');
  }
}

<ul *ngIf="tags && tags.length">
  <a *ngFor="let tag of tags">
    <li>{{tag}}</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You caon try something like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
console.log(params['name']);
});
```